# How to structure JNI call to avoid memory leak?

Tags: java, c++, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

So I have the following JNIManager class in Java. In this, class, as you can see, I define a native method called setUpBackGround();

```
public class JNIManager{
   public native void setUpBackground();
   public void messageMe(byte[] byteArray);
}
```

I then have another class implemented in native (C) code. Let's call this class Background Class. This class does some background work and calls on the messageMe() method of the JNIManager class passing it a byte[].

```
class Background{
   JNIEnv* mJNIEnv;
   jbyteArray mArray;
   jobject mJObject;    

   Background(JNIEnv * env, jobject jObject){
      mArray = env->NewByteArray(1040);
      mJNIEnv = env;
      mJObject = jObject;
   }

   virtual ~Background(){
      mJNIEnv->DeleteLocalRef(mArray); //is this necessary?
   }

   void someMethod(){
      jclass manager = mJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(mJObject);
      jmethodID method = mJNIEnv->GetMethodID(manager, "messageMe", "([B)V");                         
      mJNIEnv->CallVoidMethod(mJObject, method, mArray);
      mJNIEnv->DeleteLocalRef(manager); // is this necessary?
   }

}
```

Now, in native method, setUpBackground, I do the following,

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_test_JNIManager_setUpBackground
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jo){
    Background* back = new Background(env,jo);
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, in another class's method, I create an instance of JNIManager and invoke the native method setUpBackground().

```
otherMethod(){
    JNIManager jniManager = new JNIManager();
    jniManager.setUpBackground();
}
```

I have 2 questions about this whole setup.

1) When the jniManager goes out of scope at the end of the above method, will the Background class that I created dynamically with the "new" keyword automatically be garbage-collected? I am thinking it will not and will lead to a memory leak. Is this correct? What can I do to correct it if so?

2) Are the DeleteLocalRef() calls necessary to avoid memory leaks or will the JVM take care of the task of deleting them once they are no longer in use?

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE - following nneonneo's answer

```
public class JNIManager{
       private long nativeHandle;

       public JNIManager(){
          nativeHandle = setUpBackground();
       }

       public native long setUpBackground();
       public native void releaseBackground(long handle);
       public void messageMe(byte[] byteArray) {//do some stuff};
}
```

Updated Background class

```
class Background{

public:

   JavaVM* mJvm;
   JNIEnv* mJNIEnv;
   jobject mJObject;
   jbyteArray mArray;
   int file;

   Background(JNIEnv * env, jobject jObject){
      env->GetJavaVM(&mJvm);
      attachToThread();
      mJObject = env->NewGlobalRef(jObject);
      mArray = env->NewByteArray(1040);
      file = 1;    //Does this need to be a globalRef ? 
   }

   void destroy(){
      mJNIEnv->DeleteGlobalRef(mArray);
      mJNIEnv->DeleteGlobalRef(mJObject);
      mJvm = NULL;
      mJNIEnv = NULL;
      file = 0;
   }

   void someMethod(){
      attachToThread();
      jclass manager = mJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(mJObject);
      jmethodID method = mJNIEnv->GetMethodID(manager, "messageMe", "([B)V");                         
      mJNIEnv->CallVoidMethod(mJObject, method, mArray);
      mJNIEnv->DeleteLocalRef(manager);
      detachFromThread();
   }

   void attachToThread(){
     mJvm->AttachCurrentThread(&mJNIEnv, NULL);
   }

   void detachFromThread(){
     mJvm->DetachCurrentThread();
   }

}
```

Updated native methods

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_test_JNIManager_setUpBackground
   (JNIEnv * env, jobject jo){
     Background* back = new Background(env,jo);
     return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(back);
 }

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_test_JNIManager_releaseBackground
   (JNIEnv * env, jobject jo, jlong handle){
     Background* back = reinterpret_cast<Background* back>(handle);
     back.destroy();
     delete back;
}
```

Updated otherMethod

```
otherMethod(){
    JNIManager jniManager = new JNIManager();

     //Do some stuff...

    jniManager.releaseBackground();
}
```

I am not sure of the first point.

"JNIEnvs may not remain the same between JNI calls  (in particular, two different threads will have different JNIEnvs)".

Does this mean that once the setupBackground() JNI call returns, the current thread is deleted? 
Since the Background class is created in this thread, won't the methods of this class (such as someMethod()) run on the same thread? If not, is the attachToThread() method defined the right way to get the current thread and use its JNIEnv*?

I basically need the Background object that is created to be in existence throughout the lifetime of JNIManager. The Background object's someMethod() is then sporadically invoked
(by some external class) and this will then make a call to the messageMe() method in the
JNIManager class (as can be seen in the code).

Comment: who and how will call `Background::someMethod()`?

Comment: It is basically a listener method that is provided inside of the Background class that I am using..I am just extending the Background class and overriding the listener to do some custom stuff. As such, it is called by the library code..

Answer (score 6):

You are doing several things wrong.

1. You cannot store a reference to `JNIEnv` after the JNI method returns. `JNIEnv`s may not remain the same between JNI calls (in particular, two different threads will have different `JNIEnv`s, and the Java class finalizers may run on a separate thread).
2. You cannot store LocalRefs after a JNI method returns. All local refs are deleted upon return from a JNI function. If you need to retain a reference to an object, use a global reference (which you are then responsible for deleting). Both `mArray` and `mJObject` must be global references.
3. Yes, you have a leak. You do not `delete` `back` anywhere, and in fact you don't even store its address anywhere so it **will** leak. If you intend `Background` to be a singleton class, then actually use a proper singleton pattern to implement it. If you intend the lifetime of `Background` to be tied to the lifetime of the `JNIManager`, then you have to add appropriate finalization code to `JNIManager` to destroy the `Background` instance (and store the `Background` instance somewhere, e.g. on the `JNIManager` class instance).

Comment: I have made some changes to the original code as you suggested..could you take a look and let me know if this the right way to do it? Thanks!